# Class Syntax Issue

Tags: c++, class

Super new to this. Please explain in the dumbest way possible.

I want to call the `.size()` function on an array and make it a parameter of the `for` loop so I can go through it index by index. However, when I type:

```
encryptedtxt.size()
```

I get an error suggesting I need a class specifier. When I include the specifier:

```
FileDecrypt.encryptedtxt.size()
```

It says the type name is not allowed.

I've included the relevant stuff below, if it helps understand my question.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class FileDecrypt {
public:
    int x;
    int encryptedtxt[4];
    ifstream encryptedchars;

    int readin() {
        encryptedchars.open("encrypted.txt");
        for (int i=0;i < 4;i++) {
            encryptedchars >> encryptedtxt[i];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int size = FileDecrypt.encryptedtxt.size();
    int decrypt() {
        for (int j = 0;j < encryptedtxt.size();j++) {
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Dumbest way possible. There is no `size` function on an array.

In C++ you should use `std::vector` or `std::array` both of which have `size` functions.

E.g.

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 4> encryptedtxt;
```

Regular arrays are something that C++ inherits from C, but C++ has far superior alternatives. Either `std::array` if you want a fixed size array, or `std::vector` if you want a variable size array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I did not know std::array and C arrays are different. How do they differ, if you don't mind another simple question?

Comment: @Dhyana The most obvious difference is that std::array has a size function. Another difference is that a std::array can be copied or assigned, so `a = b;` is illegal if a and b are arrays, but fine if a and b are std::arrays, see [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for full details.